# setting a path in cygwin

Tags: python, module, path, cygwin

im getting the error

```
        ImportError: No module named matplotlib
```

But I have it installed under python2.7 and can see the location.  Is there a way I can get cygwin to recognize it if I know the file location? When I ask "which matplotlib" it just tells me its not in a odd folder location chain like such

```
 $ which matplotlib
which: no matplotlib in (/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/NVIDIA Corporation/PhysX/Common:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Silverfrost/FTN95:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Common Files/Microsoft Shared/Windows Live:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Common Files/Microsoft Shared/Windows Live:/cygdrive/c/windows/system32:/cygdrive/c/windows:/cygdrive/c/windows/System32/Wbem:/cygdrive/c/windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/WIDCOMM/Bluetooth Software:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/WIDCOMM/Bluetooth Software/syswow64:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Pinnacle/Shared Files:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Pinnacle/Shared Files/Filter:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Windows Live/Shared:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/QuickTime/QTSystem:%CYGWIN_HOME%/bin:%CYGWIN_HOME%/sbin:%CYGWIN_HOME%/usr/bin:%CYGWIN_HOME%/usr/sbin:%CYGWIN_HOME%/usr/local/bin:%CYGWIN_HOME%/usr/local/sbin:/cygdrive/c/Anaconda:/cygdrive/c/Anaconda/Scripts:/usr/lib/python2.7/user/scripts:/usr/lib/python2.7/User:/usr/lib/python2.7/User/Scripts:/usr/lib/lapack:/usr/openwin/bin:/cygdrive/c/python27:/cygdrive/c/Anaconda:/cygdrive/c/Anaconda/python:/c/Anaconda:/cygdrive/Anaconda:/cygdrive/c/Anaconda:/cygdrive/c/Anaconda:/cygdrive/c/Anaconda/Python27:/cygdrive/c/Python27:/cygdrive/c/Python27)
```

(There are several mentions of Anaconda but that I believe is remnants of trying to place it within Cygwin when I was messing around one day)

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
import sys
a="your path to python/lib/site-packages"
sys.path.append(a)
```

Then you should be able to do `import matplotlib` from cygwin